# Python-uno not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, libreoffice, uno

I have a python project developed in Ubuntu 12.04 using python 2.7 . It is using pyoo and uno installed using

`pip install pyoo`

`apt-get -y install python-uno`

While using this project on ubuntu to 14.04 .

a) while installing `apt-get install python-uno` it says 
   Package python-uno is not available, but is referred to by another
   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted,
   or is only available from another source
   However the following packages replace it:
   `libreoffice-script-provider-python`
  So i have installed `apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python`

b) On ubuntu 14.14 it shows following error

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/mdm/rawtoreportv5/ditupload.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ditmgmt.ditmt import *
  File "/data/mdm/rawtoreportv5/ditmgmt/ditmt.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyoo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyoo.py", line 26, in <module>
    FORMAT_TEXT = uno.getConstantByName('com.sun.star.i18n.NumberFormatIndex.TEXT')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getConstantByName'
`
```

What should i do to run it properly on ubuntu 14.04 with python 2.7?

Comment: Do an apt-cache search and it might throw up something

Comment: Please elaborate how it relevant to my query...!!

Answer (score -1):

On newer Ubuntu systems, always remember to use Python 3 when using the [Python-UNO bridge](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/PyUNO_bridge).  These commands worked on my system:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ sudo pip3 install pyoo
$ python3
>>> import pyoo
```

By the way, even without `pyoo`, this should work as long as `libreoffice-script-provider-python` is installed:

```
$ python3
>>> import uno
>>> uno.getConstantByName('com.sun.star.i18n.NumberFormatIndex.TEXT')
49
```